# Issue Pulling UID from Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've seen many youtube videos and previously answered questions on this exact subject, but for some reason my code is not working.

I want to display the user's name that is stored, but I can't pull the `UID` from FireBase. At this point, the user should be logged in so I don't think it's an issue of forcing the `UID`. Any help would be great.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8arX.png)
[Firebase Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F46YZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updated your question with more information.

Post the code you have referenced in "my code is not working"!

Answer (score 2):

You can get your uid as:

```
var ref : DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference().child("klaw-unpw").child("users")
```

And in your viewdidload add this code:

```
ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    print(snapshot.value)
             }) { (error) in
        print(error)
        }
```

But it will be good if you will start your structure with "users" instead of "klaw-unpw".

Hope it will work for you.